# Hash function in C# returns different value on localhost developing server than in production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, sha1

I have an aspx application where I make a hash to send it to the bank so that a monetary transaction be made. I'm experiencing a very strange problem: when I run the application locally in the development server of visual studio 2010, the hash gets computed correctly, but in the published application in the production server, the hash no longer gets computed correctly, it doesn't throw any error, but the resulting hash is not correct (saying that it's incorrect doesn't mean that its not a hash, but it's not the expected hash)

The function that returns the hash is as follows:

```
string codificar = afiliacion.ToString().Trim() + 
                   tienda.ToString().Trim() +     
                   terminal.Trim() + 
                   total_orden.ToString().Trim() + 
                   moneda.ToString().Trim() +     
                   numOrd.ToString().Trim();

SHA1 cod = new SHA1Managed();
UTF8Encoding codificado = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] stream = codificado.GetBytes(codificar);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var hash = cod.ComputeHash(stream);
foreach (var b in hash)
{
    sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
}

foreach (var laorden in categoriaBuscados)
{
    TNumsOrdenAFoliosMovimiento registro = new   TNumsOrdenAFoliosMovimiento();
    registro.numOrden = laorden.NumOrden;
    registro.Digest = sb.ToString().ToLower();
    try
    {
        modelo.TNumsOrdenAFoliosMovimiento.AddObject(registro);
        modelo.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception el)
    {
        Response.Write(el.Message);
    }
```

Any suggestion will be welcome greatly, because I have no idea why this may be happening. I mean, it's theoretically impossible that the same code works differently from the local version to the published version, isn't it?

Comment: Can you expand how you determined it wasn't the correct hash?

Comment: Give an example of the string `codificar` and the hash you expect and the one you get.

Comment: The 32-bit vs 64-bit is one of most probable reasons here.

Comment: @MarkNash This is not the same. `GetHashCode()` is not used here.

Comment: `ToString` could produce different representations depending on the locale of the machine.  Are they the same on the local and production machines?

Comment: Ok @Magnus the string codificar would be like 70913901234001100484201544 and the hash expected a4acd123b8416a72f9fb5698240cebedfa59e485 though the generated hash (in the production server is 0554ea87fa6357cb147872b10e9a9f289dab5535

Comment: Is `codificar` the same locally and remotely? `codificado`?  Where are you seeing the first difference?

Comment: @cahinton I don't know for sure because I'm not debugging the remote application. Right now I don't have access to the public ip except on my IPhone.

Answer (score 4):

Since the strings are not displayed to users and used only to generate hashes, update the `ToString` calls to `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` -- that will ensure the are stringified using the same rules locally and on the production server.

```
string codificar = afiliacion.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim() + 
                   tienda.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim() +     
                   terminal.Trim() + 
                   total_orden.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim() + 
                   moneda.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim() +     
                   numOrd.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim();
```

Comment: I tried using a call like `registro.Digest = sb.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLower();` but it shows me an error "no overload method ToString() takes one arguments". I tried defining the cultureinfo first doing `CultureInfo Inv = new CultureInfo("");` and then `ToString(Inv)` but I still get that error. What's the way to do it?

Comment: @gerardoflores I meant the `ToString`s when you are building codificar.

Comment: I believe the ToString() method to use with StringBuilder doesn't include an overload with only one argument, only `ToString(int startindex, int length)`. So I can't update the ToString method that converts (initally) the StringBuilder

Comment: @gerardoflores Updated my answer to be more clear as to where the InvariantCulture should be used.  Are `afiliacion`, `tienda`, etc, etc, `StringBuilders` as well?

Comment: Thank you, it seemed like a pretty good idea but unfortunately it's not working, it still only returns the correct hash when running locally (Sigh)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like the problem was with the dll mscorlib that was in the production server, which version was different from the one I use in development. So eventually I came up with another solution and instead of using the UTF8Encoding class and get the bytes from the string I built the bytes using javascript then passed them to the code behind. Now the two hashes are equal and there are no more errors. Thank you all for your comments. I still do not know how to close a question here.

The javascript code I used to build the byte array is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var referencia = document.getElementById("referencia");
            console.log(referencia.value);
            referencia.value = getBytes(utf8_encode(referencia.value));
        }
        function getBytes(str) {
            var bytes = [];
            var charCode;

            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
                charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
                bytes.push((charCode & 0xFF00) >> 8);
                bytes.push(charCode & 0xFF);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
        function utf8_encode(argString) {
            if (argString === null || typeof argString === 'undefined') {
                return '';
            }

            var string = (argString + ''); // .replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").replace(/\r/g,  "\n");
            var utftext = '',
    start, end, stringl = 0;

            start = end = 0;
            stringl = string.length;
            for (var n = 0; n < stringl; n++) {
                var c1 = string.charCodeAt(n);
                var enc = null;

                if (c1 < 128) {
                    end++;
                } else if (c1 > 127 && c1 < 2048) {
                    enc = String.fromCharCode(
        (c1 >> 6) | 192, (c1 & 63) | 128
      );
                } else if ((c1 & 0xF800) != 0xD800) {
                    enc = String.fromCharCode(
        (c1 >> 12) | 224, ((c1 >> 6) & 63) | 128, (c1 & 63) | 128
      );
                } else { // surrogate pairs
                    if ((c1 & 0xFC00) != 0xD800) {
                        throw new RangeError('Unmatched trail surrogate at ' + n);
                    }
                    var c2 = string.charCodeAt(++n);
                    if ((c2 & 0xFC00) != 0xDC00) {
                        throw new RangeError('Unmatched lead surrogate at ' + (n - 1));
                    }
                    c1 = ((c1 & 0x3FF) << 10) + (c2 & 0x3FF) + 0x10000;
                    enc = String.fromCharCode(
        (c1 >> 18) | 240, ((c1 >> 12) & 63) | 128, ((c1 >> 6) & 63) | 128, (c1 & 63) |     128
      );
                }
                if (enc !== null) {
                    if (end > start) {
                        utftext += string.slice(start, end);
                    }
                    utftext += enc;
                    start = end = n + 1;
                 }
            }

            if (end > start) {
                utftext += string.slice(start, stringl);
            }

            return utftext;
        }
        </script>
```